# Why is this a CSP violation? blocked-uri = self when 'self' is explicitly allowed

Tags: content-security-policy

I cannot wrap my head around the CSP violation report below (sent by FireFox 44.0.2 / Ubuntu). What is really being blocked here and why?
It should be noted that it does not matter if I write `'self'` or (as gets automatically translated in the report) `https://www.example.com` into the CSP header.
Also, I am not aware of anything missing from the rendered page.
So what can I do against it? (Apparently, I should not add reporting in my live site if every page triggers a fake violation report)

```
{
    "csp-report":{
        "blocked-uri":"self",
        "document-uri":"https://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz.html",
        "original-policy":"report-uri https://reportserver.example.com/ContentSecurityPolicy-report.php; 
            default-src https://www.example.com; 
            style-src https://example.com https://www.example.com https://fonts.googleapis.com; 
            script-src https://www.example.com https://code.jquery.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; 
            font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com",
        "referrer":"https://www.example.com/foo/bar/wtf.html",
        "source-file":"https://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz.html",
        "violated-directive":"style-src https://example.com https://www.example.com https://fonts.googleapis.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this deployed anywhere where I can take a look? I can't think of anything short of a bug in firefox based on your description.

Comment: @oreoshake You can see this (from external in "report only" mode) on `https://www.redeker.de/`. Meanwhile I somewhat suspect that what is blocked might rather be some `'unsafe-inline'` style, i.e.,  `style="..."` added to tags, but that is not visible in the html source because it gets added per script later (where the script itself is allowed per CSP). But I'd be happy if you could confirm this suspicion.

Comment: Yep, unsafe-inline was necessary. I often find the developer console is more useful than the reports sometimes. CSP reporting has many known issues, and reporting on inline content is one of them.

Comment: @oreoshake I suppose with developer console you mean that of Chrome (whihc I now found out to be very helpful), cause the one in Firefox (which I originally used) left me with a lot of guesswork ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting your policy to:

```
default-src 'self'; style-src example.com www.example.com 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' https://code.jquery.com https://ajax.googleapis.com; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com 'self';
```

I don't see any violations. I added the 'unsafe-inline' to style src, and 'self' to font-src.

Comment: I had problems with inline styles and inline javascript until I added `'unsafe-inline'` to those individual policies, or to the `default-src` policy. When you get `"blocked-uri": "self"`, it's an indication that there is something inline which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of CSP report (in September 2021) that doesn't make any sense with user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
```

I'd assume that it's either an updated browser hitting some old bug or some browser extension that changes both the user agent and the browser behavior.

And yes, the server emitted `Content-Security-Policy` did include `script-src 'self' 'report-sample' ...` even though the reported `violated-directive` did not include either `self` nor `report-sample`. I haven't bothered to test with that old Firefox but I'd assume that it doesn't support `'report-sample'` and it causes it to incorrectly parse the policy resulting in `'self'` getting dropped, too.

If you see this same report from some more modern user agent, I'd be interested to know more details about your case.

This bug might also be related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1236222